# Can we extend the box counting dimension to unbounded sets?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

The box counting dimension of a set, $X$ in a metric space looks at boxes of dimension $\varepsilon$ and how many, $N(\varepsilon)$ are needed to covert $X$ and then says

$$dim_{box}(X) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}{\frac{\log{N(\varepsilon)}}{\log{\varepsilon}}}$$

Let's use $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the Euclidean metric as our metric. Can we extend this definition to unbounded sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the number of boxes needed is infinite? For example, the box counting dimension of Cantor's middle third set is $\log{2}/\log{3}$. But, what if we have an countable number of copies of this (e.g. stacked above above one another at a distance of $1$).

Comment: In general dimensions should be local. You can consider a "local box-counting dimension" at a given point, namely the box-counting dimension of a ball of radius $r$ as $r \to 0$, if this limit exists.

Comment: Also for what it's worth, in Euclidean space (or any separable metric space) one cannot have uncountably many copies of anything stacked at distance $1$.

Comment: @MW thanks, sorry, that was a mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan why can't we do this as $r \to \infty$? If that limit exists, I guess it would be something like the supremum of the dimension over any (bounded? compact? something) subset?

Comment: @roundsquare have you looked at the Hausdorff dimension? it is generally considered to have more natural properties than the box-counting dimension

Comment: @Albert yeah, I have looked at it a bit. I am more familiar with box counting dimension which is why I asked about that. Does Hausdorff dimension act better if we let $r \to \infty$?

Comment: @roundsquare the box-counting dimension is defined for compact sets. the Hausdorff dimension is defined for any set (it doesn't need to be bounded)